# Text chatting website in python

Tags: python, network-programming, erlang, chat, tornado

I aspire to create a text chatting website with some extra features. As for the core text chatting part, is python an appropriate language for such a kind ? If so, is their any libraries which help in this process.

I would also require real time data being pushed back to the browser, implying i would be using the web-sockets also. Is tornado the appropriate choice of server ? I am a newbie in terms of network based application or website.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: I was looking for an answer with supported libraries or examples of projects.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado is a non block webserver with a chat demo already created.

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/chat

From the tornado website:

> The framework is distinct from most mainstream web server frameworks
>   (and certainly most Python frameworks) because it is non-blocking and
>   reasonably fast. Because it is non-blocking and uses epoll or kqueue,
>   it can handle thousands of simultaneous standing connections, which
>   means it is ideal for real-time web services. We built the web server
>   specifically to handle FriendFeed's real-time features — every active
>   user of FriendFeed maintains an open connection to the FriendFeed
>   servers. (For more information on scaling servers to support thousands
>   of clients, see The C10K problem.)

Sounds like it would be worth the time to look into.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own simple chat engine. In any case it's not bad to see the next libraries:
http://docs.python.org/library/asynchat.html,
http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html.

The links contain examples.

An example of usage: start it on some port and access it from javascript.